# WHAT is "IN" in DNS records?

Tags: dns, key, dkim, dmarc

What is the proper meaning of the "IN" word in DNS records? DNS records are an important part of DNS zones. So I want to know that there is an "IN" word included in every record. what is the meaning?

It would help clarify what such a piece of information in DNS is?

Thank you for making all the efforts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple **IN**ternet search would have brought you to Wikipedia, where the following is stated on DNS Record Classes:

> The CLASS of a record is set to IN (for Internet) for common DNS
>   records involving Internet hostnames, servers, or IP addresses. In
>   addition, the classes Chaos (CH) and Hesiod (HS) exist.[34] Each class
>   is an independent name space with potentially different delegations of
>   DNS zones.

Find the link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Resource_records).

Comment: Ironically, the simple INternet search brought me here